# How to remove categories from magento top menu without removing from side bar

Tags: php, magento, navigation, magento-1.9

i want to know the method to remove or hide categories from top navigation bar of magento. As i m using magento 1.9.2.4. please guide me. i just want to remove category links only  from navigation bar

Comment: Check this link hope it can help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18670/hide-category-from-top-navigation-but-show-in-side-navigation

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the Magento admin to “show in the navigation”. 
It’s under

```
Catalog > Manage Categories > category-name > General Information > Include in Navigation Menu*
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: but this also removes the categories from the sidebar menu.... i want to remove from top navigation menu

Comment: Check this link hope it can help you

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18670/hide-category-from-top-navigation-but-show-in-side-navigation

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<catalog_category_layered>
 <reference name="left">
  <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
  <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.categories" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```